# fancybox not working with validation engine

Tags: jquery, jsp, fancybox

I want to launch fancybox after validation engine validation got success.... code that I am using are mentioned below....

```
<button type="button" class="addcncl" value="<s:message code='createMonitorProfile' />" name="createProfile" id="createProfile" ><s:message code='createMonitorProfile' /></button>

$("#createProfile").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
        'overlayColor'      : '#000',
        'autoSize'          : false,
        'autoDimensions'    :false,
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.7,
        'scrolling'         :'yes',
});
$("#createProfile").bind("click", function() {
    if($('#createMonitorProfileForm').validationEngine('validate')) {
          //if this condition is true then I want to upload fancybox content 
          //with ajax request.
    }
});
```

problem that i am getting is that my fancybox appearing before the validation happens...

Comment: is the selector `#createProfile` the form itself (and actually what you see inside fancybox)? ... and `#createMonitorProfileForm` a temporary selector created by the validation engine? ... and last, what should be the content of fancybox after validation engine success?

Answer (score 0):

For me is working like that

```
if ($("#createMonitorProfileForm").validationEngine('validate')) {
    console.log("form is ok");
}
```